# MailChimp HTML email template edit.. responsive images not filling width 100%

Tags: html, css, email

I am really about to throw my mac out the window, but thought someone genius here might be able to help..

I have modified a responsive HTML email template from MailChimp and everything is working great, all views fine on everything in litmus EXCEPT for my two column images do not stretch to 100% of the width when the 480px breakpoint hits..

The template originally worked and I don't think I have changed anything that would of broken it but I obviously must be doing something incorrect! the large picture scales down to the smaller width fine.

Hoping someone can easily spot the error of my ways, although the template is a bit code heavy..

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Latest Projects</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
        #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
        .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
        .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
        body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
        table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
        img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;} /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */

        /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ RESET STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
        body{margin:0; padding:0;}
        img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
        table{border-collapse:collapse !important;}
        body, #bodyTable, #bodyCell{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}

        /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ TEMPLATE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */

        /* ========== Page Styles ========== */

        #bodyCell{padding:20px;}
        #templateContainer{width:600px;}

        /**
        * @tab Page
        * @section background style
        * @tip Set the background color and top border for your email. You may want to choose colors that match your company's branding.
        * @theme page
        */
        body, #bodyTable{
            /*@editable*/ background-color:#DEE0E2;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Page
        * @section background style
        * @tip Set the background color and top border for your email. You may want to choose colors that match your company's branding.
        * @theme page
        */
        #bodyCell{
            /*@editable*/ border-top:4px solid #FFFFFF;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Page
        * @section email border
        * @tip Set the border for your email.
        */
        #templateContainer{
            /*@editable*/ border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Page
        * @section heading 1
        * @tip Set the styling for all first-level headings in your emails. These should be the largest of your headings.
        * @style heading 1
        */
        h1{
            /*@editable*/ color:#202020 !important;
            display:block;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:26px;
            /*@editable*/ font-style:normal;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:bold;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
            /*@editable*/ letter-spacing:normal;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Page
        * @section heading 2
        * @tip Set the styling for all second-level headings in your emails.
        * @style heading 2
        */
        h2{
            /*@editable*/ color:#404040 !important;
            display:block;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:20px;
            /*@editable*/ font-style:normal;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:bold;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
            /*@editable*/ letter-spacing:normal;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Page
        * @section heading 3
        * @tip Set the styling for all third-level headings in your emails.
        * @style heading 3
        */
        h3{
            /*@editable*/ color:#606060 !important;
            display:block;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:16px;
            /*@editable*/ font-style:italic;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
            /*@editable*/ letter-spacing:normal;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Page
        * @section heading 4
        * @tip Set the styling for all fourth-level headings in your emails. These should be the smallest of your headings.
        * @style heading 4
        */
        h4{
            /*@editable*/ color:#808080 !important;
            display:block;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:14px;
            /*@editable*/ font-style:italic;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
            /*@editable*/ letter-spacing:normal;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
        }

        /* ========== Header Styles ========== */

        /**
        * @tab Header
        * @section preheader style
        * @tip Set the background color and bottom border for your email's preheader area.
        * @theme header
        */
        #templatePreheader{
            /*@editable*/ background-color:#F4F4F4;
            /*@editable*/ border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Header
        * @section preheader text
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's preheader text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        */
        .preheaderContent{
            /*@editable*/ color:#808080;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:10px;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:125%;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Header
        * @section preheader link
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's preheader links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
        .preheaderContent a:link, .preheaderContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .preheaderContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
            /*@editable*/ color:#606060;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
            /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Header
        * @section header style
        * @tip Set the background color and borders for your email's header area.
        * @theme header
        */
        #templateHeader{
            /*@editable*/ background-color:#FFFFFF;
            /*@editable*/ border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
            /*@editable*/ border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
        }

                #projectHeader{
            /*@editable*/ background-color:#F4F4F4;
            /*@editable*/ border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
            /*@editable*/ border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
        }


        /**
        * @tab Header
        * @section header text
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's header text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        */
        .headerContent{
            /*@editable*/ color:#444444;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:20px;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:bold;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
            /*@editable*/ padding-top:0;
            /*@editable*/ padding-right:0;
            /*@editable*/ padding-bottom:0;
            /*@editable*/ padding-left:0;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
            /*@editable*/ vertical-align:middle;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Header
        * @section header link
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's header links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
        .headerContent a:link, .headerContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .headerContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
            /*@editable*/ color:#EB4102;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
            /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
        }

        #headerImage{
            height:auto;
            max-width:600px;
        }

        /* ========== Body Styles ========== */

        /**
        * @tab Body
        * @section body style
        * @tip Set the background color and borders for your email's body area.
        */
        .templateBody{
            /*@editable*/ background-color:#FFFFFF;
            /*@editable*/ border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
            /*@editable*/ border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Body
        * @section body text
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's main content text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        * @theme main
        */
        .bodyContent{
            /*@editable*/ color:#444444;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:20px;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:140%;
            padding-top:15px;
            padding-right:20px;
            padding-bottom:15px;
            padding-left:20px;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Body
        * @section body link
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's main content links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
        .bodyContent a:link, .bodyContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .bodyContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
            /*@editable*/ color:#EB4102;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
            /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
        }

        .bodyContent img{
            display:inline;
            height:auto;
            max-width:560px;
        }

        /* ========== Column Styles ========== */

        .templateColumnContainer{display:inline; width:260px;}

        /**
        * @tab Columns
        * @section column style
        * @tip Set the background color and borders for your email's column area.
        */
        .templateColumns{
            /*@editable*/ background-color:#FFFFFF;
            /*@editable*/ border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
            /*@editable*/ border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Columns
        * @section left column text
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's left column content text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        */
        .leftColumnContent{
            /*@editable*/ color:#444444;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:20px;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:130%;
            padding-top:0;
            padding-right:0;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            padding-left:0;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;

        }

        /**
        * @tab Columns
        * @section left column link
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's left column content links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
        .leftColumnContent a:link, .leftColumnContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .leftColumnContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
            /*@editable*/ color:#EB4102;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
            /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Columns
        * @section right column text
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's right column content text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        */
        .rightColumnContent{
            /*@editable*/ color:#444444;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:20px;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:130%;
            padding-top:0;
            padding-right:0;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            padding-left:0;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Columns
        * @section right column link
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's right column content links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
        .rightColumnContent a:link, .rightColumnContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .rightColumnContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
            /*@editable*/ color:#EB4102;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
            /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
        }

        .leftColumnContent img, .rightColumnContent img{
            display:inline;
            height:auto;
            max-width:260px;
        }

        /* ========== Footer Styles ========== */

        /**
        * @tab Footer
        * @section footer style
        * @tip Set the background color and borders for your email's footer area.
        * @theme footer
        */
        #templateFooter{
            /*@editable*/ background-color:#F4F4F4;
            /*@editable*/ border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Footer
        * @section footer text
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's footer text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
        * @theme footer
        */
        .footerContent{
            /*@editable*/ color:#808080;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:10px;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:150%;
            padding-top:20px;
            padding-right:20px;
            padding-bottom:20px;
            padding-left:20px;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:center;
        }

        /**
        * @tab Footer
        * @section footer link
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's footer links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
        .footerContent a:link, .footerContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .footerContent a .yshortcuts, .footerContent a span /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
            /*@editable*/ color:#606060;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
            /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
        }

        /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ MOBILE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */

        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC MOBILE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
            body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
            body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */

            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ MOBILE RESET STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
            #bodyCell{padding:10px !important;}

            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ MOBILE TEMPLATE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */

            /* ======== Page Styles ======== */

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section template width
            * @tip Make the template fluid for portrait or landscape view adaptability. If a fluid layout doesn't work for you, set the width to 300px instead.
            */
            #templateContainer{
                max-width:600px !important;
                /*@editable*/ width:100% !important;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section heading 1
            * @tip Make the first-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
            */
            h1{
                /*@editable*/ font-size:24px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:100% !important;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section heading 2
            * @tip Make the second-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
            */
            h2{
                /*@editable*/ font-size:20px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:100% !important;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section heading 3
            * @tip Make the third-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
            */
            h3{
                /*@editable*/ font-size:18px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:100% !important;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section heading 4
            * @tip Make the fourth-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
            */
            h4{
                /*@editable*/ font-size:16px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:100% !important;
            }




.buttonPad {
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
            /* ======== Header Styles ======== */

            #templatePreheader{display:block !important;} /* Hide the template preheader to save space */

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section header image
            * @tip Make the main header image fluid for portrait or landscape view adaptability, and set the image's original width as the max-width. If a fluid setting doesn't work, set the image width to half its original size instead.
            */
            #headerImage{
                height:auto !important;
                /*@editable*/ max-width:600px !important;
                /*@editable*/ width:100% !important;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section header text
            * @tip Make the header content text larger in size for better readability on small screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
            */
            .headerContent{
                /*@editable*/ font-size:20px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:125% !important;
            }

            /* ======== Body Styles ======== */

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section body image
            * @tip Make the main body image fluid for portrait or landscape view adaptability, and set the image's original width as the max-width. If a fluid setting doesn't work, set the image width to half its original size instead.
            */
            .bodyImage{
                height:auto !important;
                /*@editable*/ max-width:560px !important;
                /*@editable*/ width:100% !important;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section body text
            * @tip Make the body content text larger in size for better readability on small screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
            */
            .bodyContent{
                /*@editable*/ font-size:14px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:125% !important;
            }

            p {
                /*@editable*/ font-size:14px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:125% !important;
            }



            /* ======== Column Styles ======== */

            .templateColumnContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section column image
            * @tip Make the column image fluid for portrait or landscape view adaptability, and set the image's original width as the max-width. If a fluid setting doesn't work, set the image width to half its original size instead.
            */
            .columnImage{
                height:auto !important;
                /*@editable*/ max-width:560px !important;
                /*@editable*/ width:100% !important;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section left column text
            * @tip Make the left column content text larger in size for better readability on small screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
            */
            .leftColumnContent{
                /*@editable*/ font-size:16px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:125% !important;
                padding-bottom:20px;

            }


            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section right column text
            * @tip Make the right column content text larger in size for better readability on small screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
            */
            .rightColumnContent{
                /*@editable*/ font-size:16px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:125% !important;
            }

            /* ======== Footer Styles ======== */

            /**
            * @tab Mobile Styles
            * @section footer text
            * @tip Make the body content text larger in size for better readability on small screens.
            */
            .footerContent{
                /*@editable*/ font-size:14px !important;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:115% !important;
            }

            .footerContent a{display:block !important;} /* Place footer social and utility links on their own lines, for easier access */
        }

        .latest {
            color:#9A9A9A;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:20px;
            /*@editable*/ padding-top:0;
            /*@editable*/ padding-right:0;
            /*@editable*/ padding-bottom:0;
            /*@editable*/ padding-left:0;
            margin-top:10px;
            margin-bottom:10px;

             }



             .latestprojects{
            /*@editable*/ color:#444444;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
            /*@editable*/ font-size:20px;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:bold;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
            /*@editable*/ padding-top:0;
            /*@editable*/ padding-right:0;
            /*@editable*/ padding-bottom:0;
            /*@editable*/ padding-left:0;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
            /*@editable*/ vertical-align:middle;
        }


        .button{

            padding-top:0px;
            padding-right:0px;
            padding-bottom:20px;
            padding-left:20px;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
        }

        .unsubscribe {
            font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
    font-size:9px;
    line-height:12px;
    }

    </style>
</head>


<!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
    <center>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">



<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer">

    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">


            <!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templatePreheader">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent" style="padding-top:10px; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:20px;" mc:edit="preheader_content00">

                        <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="images/twitter30.png" alt="twitter" /></a>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><img src="images/linkedin30.png" alt="linkedin" /></a> 

                    </td>
                                        <!-- *|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE|* -->
                    <td valign="top" width="180" class="preheaderContent" style="padding-top:10px; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:0;text-align:right;" mc:edit="preheader_content01">

                        <strong>July 2015</strong><br /><webversion>View in browser</webversion>

                    </td>
                                            <!-- *|END:IF|* -->
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- // END PREHEADER -->

        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">

            <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateHeader">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="headerContent">

                        <img src="images/aw_header_600.gif" alt="header" style="max-width:600px; margin-bottom:0px;" id="headerImage" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">

            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="projectHeader">  

                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="headerContent" style="background:#FFFFFF">

                        <p class="latest">LATEST PROJECTS</p>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- // END HEADER -->

        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">                 

            <!-- BEGIN HERO // -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateBody">
                <tr>
                    <td class="bodyContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0;">

                        <img src="images/openplan_project.jpg" alt="Open Plan Office" style="max-width:560px; margin-top:0px;" class="bodyImage" mc:label="body_image" mc:edit="body_image" mc:allowtext />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content00"> COLLABORATIVE OPEN PLAN OFFICE 
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="button" mc:edit="body_content00"><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/seemore.gif" alt="see more" /></a>

                    </td>
                </tr>


            </table>
            <!-- // END HERO -->

        </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">                            

            <!-- BEGIN COLUMNS // -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumns" style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">

                        <!-- BEGIN LEFT COLUMN // -->                   
                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="templateColumnContainer">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="leftColumnContent">

                                    <img src="images/executivesuite_project.jpg" alt="Executive Suite" style="max-width:260px;" class="columnImage" mc:label="left_column_image" mc:edit="left_column_image" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" class="leftColumnContent" mc:edit="body_content00"> EXECUTIVE SUITE AT FLOPLAST </td>   
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" class="buttonpad"><a href="http://www.google.com"><img class="buttonPad" src="images/seemore.gif" alt="see more"/></a>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- // END LEFT COLUMN-->         

                        <!-- BEGIN RIGHT COLUMN // -->                     
                        <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="templateColumnContainer">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rightColumnContent">

                                    <img src="images/seminars_news.jpg" alt="BBFC Logo" style="max-width:260px;" class="columnImage" mc:label="right_column_image" mc:edit="right_column_image" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" class="rightColumnContent" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:140%">SPACE FOR MORE SEMINARS</td>    
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">

                                    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/readmore.gif" alt="read more" /></a>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- // END RIGHT COLUMN-->  

                    </td>                   
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- // END COLUMNS -->   

        </td>
    </tr> 



    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">


            <!-- BEGIN FOOTER // -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateFooter">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="footerContent" mc:edit="footer_content00">

                        <img src="images/forward30.png" alt="forward"/><img src="images/signup30.png" alt="Newsletter Signup"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- // END FOOTER -->


        </td>
    </tr>



</table>
<!-- // END TEMPLATE -->




                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </center>
                </body><!-- // END BODY -->
            </html>
```

Comment: Try changing the max-width inline styles of your 2col images from 260px to 560px (alt="Executive Suite" style="max-width:260px;").

Comment: no luck, but thanks for trying. it's set at 260 in the original template too..